# jquery focusin and focusout in angular controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Anyone see why this is causing syntax errors within my angularjs controller?:

```
$(".editRecur").focusin(function() {
    $(.recurBox).addClass("focus");
}).focusout(function() {
    $(.recurBox).removeClass("focus");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the quotes around the selector `.recurBox`

```
$(".editRecur").focusin(function() {
    $(".recurBox").addClass("focus");
}).focusout(function() {
    $(".recurBox").removeClass("focus");
});
```